# In Airflow, cannot check for equality using config variable passed

Tags: airflow

**Our DAG**

```
import func1
import func2

all_tables = [
    'tablea',
    'tableb',
    'tablec', 
    'tabled'
]

with TABLE_MONGO_LOAD:

    # Pass "table" parameter 
    this_table = "{{ dag_run.conf['table'] }}"

    this_function = func1 if this_table in all_tables else func2
    get_local_json = PythonOperator(
        task_id=f'bq_to_local',
        python_callable=this_function,
        op_kwargs={ 'table_name': this_table, 'file_name': this_table 
    )
   
    ...
```

We trigger this DAG manually, and pass { "table": "tablea" }. We want `this_function = func1 if this_table in all_tables else func2` to lead to `this_function` equalling `func`, because `tablea` is in fact in `all_tables`, however everytime we run this DAG, `func2` is returned. No matter what we pass to the config, `this_function = func1 if this_table in all_tables else func2` always returns the `else` case.

Is `this_table = "{{ dag_run.conf['table'] }}"` not returning a string? Even when I do a super basic check:

```
if this_table == 'tablea':
    print('a')
else:
    print('b')
```

this always prints b even if the config passed is `{ "table": "tablea" }`. What's going on here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the line "this_function = func1 if this_table in all_tables else func2" is running before the dag is running while airflow is interpreting that the dag is valid.

in order to check while running the DAG you should use **BranchPythonOperator**

Comment: thank you for clarifying that `this_function = func1 if this_table in all_tables else func2` runs before the DAG. I will look into BranchPythonOperator for this.